# Python Format Ctime Method

Tags: python, date, time

I am trying to get a the modified date of a file using `os.path.getmtime()` and to convert time into human readable format; it is advised to use `time.ctime()` method but it gives the name of the date and month too, which I do not want.

Is it possible to format `%d %m %Y, %H:%M`?

Currently I have code like:

```
import os.path, time

path = #path of the file

print time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(path))
```

Comment: you mean `time.strftime("%d %m %Y, %H:%M")` ?

Comment: time.strftime("%d %m %Y, %H:%M",time.ctime(os.path.getatime(path+'\\'+file))) gives an error?

Comment: It is advised by who? Does this person also advise you to use Python 1.6 instead of 2.0 because of license issues?

Comment: @MertTheGreat Since `ctime` returns a string (a non-locale-aware, fixed-format string), why would that give anything but an error?

Comment: No, if you know better way to do it please share with me this is why I am asking, thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do that with [datetime.fromtimestamp()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.fromtimestamp) like:

#### Code:

```
file_time_string = dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(__file__))
```

#### Test Code:

```
import os
import datetime as dt

file_time = dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(__file__))
print(file_time.strftime("%d %m %Y, %H:%M"))
```

#### Results:

```
24 03 2018, 16:39
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt respond and kind help.

Answer (score 7):

As documented, the [`ctime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.ctime) function just calls [`asctime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.asctime), which has a fixed format. If you want to use a `strftime`-style format string, the way to do that is to call the `strftime` function.

There are actually two ways to do this. The modern way is to construct a [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) object and call its method:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(mtime).strftime("%d %m %Y, %H:%M")
'21 03 2018, 20:34'
```

If you want to stick with the `time` module, you need a `struct_tm` to pass to its function:

```
>>> time.strftime("%d %m %Y, %H:%M", time.localtime(mtime))
'21 03 2018, 20:34'
```

If this is the only thing you're doing with timestamps, there isn't much difference. But if you want to be able to, e.g., sort them, do arithmetic on them, etc., you'll probably be happier with `datetime`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am just trying to learn. It seems like `datetime ` is the way to do it