# python - changing date modified folder output

Tags: python, python-3.x, os.walk, ctime

I have this python code which outputs the directory last modified date output.

```
import os
import time

print (time.ctime(max(os.stat(root).st_mtime for root,_,_ in os.walk('/Users/<username>/Desktop/newFolder'))))
```

output

```
Sun Jan  9 12:17:01 2022
```

Question: is there a way to change the output format with a parameter or you would have to built out a converter? To get just the year, month and day? Not to familiar with python code which I found.

desired result

```
2022-1-9 or 2022-01-9 or YYYY MM DD
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=datetime#module-datetime) module, first convert the timestamp to a [`datetime.datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=datetime#datetime.datetime) object using the `fromtimestamp` method, and then use the `strftime` method to format the time string.

```py
import os
from datetime import datetime


def convert(timestamp) -> str:
    return datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")


print(convert(max(os.stat(root).st_mtime for root,_,_ in os.walk('/Users/<username>/Desktop/newFolder'))))

# YYYY-MM-DD
```

Comment: thanks for the share.  That helped me so much :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following topic

ctime is not good for the desired action as it returns str

[Python Format Ctime Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49471004/python-format-ctime-method)

Answer (score 0):

Look for

https://github.com/srccircumflex/scripts.py

for a somewhat portable form of os.scandir

```
{'DirHead.py': {'st_atime': 1642249269,
                'st_mtime': 1642249147,
                'st_size': 6769,
                'st_uid': 1000},
 'LICENSE': {'st_atime': 1642249496,
             'st_mtime': 1642249491,
             'st_size': 1091,
             'st_uid': 1000},
 'dir/': {'st_atime': 1642251819,
          'st_mtime': 1642251819,
          'st_size': 4096,
          'st_uid': 1000}}
```

and full conversion of stats depending on their type.

```
{'DirHead.py': {'st_atime': '22.01.15-13:21',
                'st_mtime': '22.01.15-13:19',
                'st_size': {'B': 6769, 'G': 0, 'K': 7, 'M': 0},
                'st_uid': '1000'},
 'LICENSE': {'st_atime': '22.01.15-13:24',
             'st_mtime': '22.01.15-13:24',
             'st_size': {'B': 1091, 'G': 0, 'K': 1, 'M': 0},
             'st_uid': '1000'},
 'dir/': {'st_atime': '22.01.15-14:03',
          'st_mtime': '22.01.15-14:03',
          'st_size': {'B': 4096, 'G': 0, 'K': 4, 'M': 0},
          'st_uid': '1000'}}
```